# How to compute $ \sum_{x=y}^\infty \binom{x}{y}((1-p)(1-q))^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, wolfram-alpha

**Question**

How do I compute $ \sum_{x=y}^\infty \binom{x}{y} ((1-p)(1-q))^x$? $x,y$ are integers and $p, q \in (0,1)$

**Attempt**

I'm trying to compute this sum to find the mixture of a geometric and binomial distribution but I can't see how I'd do it by hand.

**Progress**

WolframAlpha gives the result: $$-\dfrac{(1-p)^y(1-q)^y(-pq+p+q)^{-y}}{pq-p-q}$$ when $|pq-p-q+1|<1$

I would like to see how I could arrive at this answer myself.

Comment: @beanshadow  I wrote the wrong question, there's also combinatorial numbers there.

Comment: @DonAntonio I edited the question, I missed the combinatorial numbers.

Comment: $x,y$ are integers, to be clear?

Comment: @FShrike yes, I will edit the question to include that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Denote $u = (1 - p)(1 - q)$. Then, the sum is $u^x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{y + k}{y} u^k$, which can be proven to be $\frac{u^x}{(1 - u)^{y + 1}}$.